# Excel custom formatting positive/negative numbers with Thousand/Million/Billion (K/M/B) suffixes

Tags: excel, custom-formatting

I know how to do each of these individually (formatting for positive/negative/zero/text values and thousand/million/billion suffixes), but I don't know how to combine them.

Using this as my base for +/- values:

`_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`

I wanted to include the suffixes for the first two using this as a basis for using suffixes:

`[<999950]#,##0,"M";[<999950000]#,##0,,"M";#,##0,,,"B"`

This would effectively fill in the first two slots of the +/- formatting, replacing `_(* #,##0_)` and `_(* (#,##0)`. The closest I can get working only ends up having a single conditional for the positive values, like so:

`[<999950000]_(* #,##0,,"M"_);_(* (#,##0,,"M");_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`

Does anyone know the best way to get something like this:

`[<999950]_(* #,##0,"M"_);_(* [<999950000]#,##0,,"M"_);_(* #,##0,,,"B"_);<same for negative values>;_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`

Any help would be appreciated, and while it would make me sad, I don't mind being told this is not possible, either. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The documentation suggests it's not. I assume you've considered a worksheet formula but ruled it out on the grounds that it converts to text?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but I've managed a couple things that seemed implausible before, so I was hopeful. That is correct, I need it to be a number value, and two fields in particular are for user input (strange as it is to use this on user input, that's what's being asked of me). I have a couple less elegant ways to get around the issue, and probably will need a couple more columns for the conversion from text back into a number...

Comment: YOu might be able to do this with conditional formatting

Comment: Well, what I could do is have a series of conditional formatting that, depending on the cell's value, applies a different custom formatting. One for positives over 1,000, another for negatives under -1,000, and a third for what remains. Or something along those lines. I was trying to do it all in one stop, but combining the two may be the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears to not be possible with a one-stop solution (which while I think doing this without a one-stop is a little messy, but I also understand why they can't just magically understand every conceivable custom format iteration), I am opting for a two-step approach:

I will have 3 custom formats. One for the positive numbers with suffixes, another for the negative numbers with suffixes, and a third that is just the "standard" positive/negative number format (displayed in the question). I will then use a series of two or three conditional formatting rules to determine which of these custom formats will be displayed.

Personally, I am going to use the +/- format as the cell's format, then apply two conditional rules that change it to the two suffix variations, but I could see the argument for using conditional formats for all three.

Thanks for the feedback and the reminder that conditional formatting exists to aid with this very kind of issue.