Custom Formatting (Billions, Millions, Thousands, ...)
I frequently use a custom format that formats numbers into billions, millions, and thousands:
[>=1000000000]0.0,,," B";[>=1000000]0.0,," M";0.0," K"

Another useful format is:
 _(\R$* #,##0.00_);_(\R$* (#,##0.00);_(\R$* "-"??_);_(@_)

This applies conditions for positive, negative, and zero values while adding the currency symbol (R$).
However, I can't seem to combine the two formats. The closest I got was:
[>=1000000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,,," B";[>=1000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,," M";_\\R$* #,##0.0," K"

This adds the currency symbol, but it doesn't address positive, negative, or zero-specific formatting.
I've tried several variations to add at least a clause for zero value, but without success (Excel returns an error), including the following three options:
[>=1000000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,,," B";[>=1000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,," M";[>0]_\\R$* #,##0.0," K";[=0]_\\R$* 0.0

[>=1000000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,,," B";[>=1000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,," M";_\\R$* #,##0.0," K";_\\R$* 0.0

[>=1000000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,,," B";[>=1000000]_\\R$* #,##0.0,," M";[>0]_\\R$* #,##0.0," K";[=0]_\\R$* 0.0

I expect it to format numbers over a billion as R$ 1.5 B; over a million as R$ 1.0 M; over zero R$ 1.0 K and zero as R$ -. Negative values should get the same formatting, but inside parenthesis.
I would really like to stick with custom formatting and not conditional formatting as it's easier for other people not to mess it up.
Does anyone have any idea why these don't work or how to fix it?

I don't think it can be done with custom formatting alone (but if I'm wrong I would love to learn how to do it).  Custom formatting takes four inputs [Positive Numbers] ; [Negative Numbers] ; [Zero] ; [Text] and I don't know of any way to do what you are asking for using this functionality alone (https://www.exceldemy.com/custom-number-formatting-with-complex-display-rules-in-excel/ .  It could be easily done with using VBA of course

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408518/excel-custom-formatting-positive-negative-numbers-with-thousand-million-billion
